# Unable to catch if a list item name is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following code which groupBY my table and select the count based on the model name:-

```
var IT360Counts = entities.Resources.Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) && (a.SystemInfo.ISSERVER == true))
  .GroupBy(a => a.SystemInfo.MODEL.ToLower())
  .Select(g => new
  {
      Action = g.Key.ToLower(),
      ItemCount = g.Count()
  }).ToLookup(a => a.Action);
```

Then i will referecne the var content such as :-

```
 IT360RouterNo =  IT360Counts["router"] == null ? 0 : IT360Counts["router"].SingleOrDefault().ItemCount,
```

The above will work well, unless when the first query does not have any router, then the second statement will always return null exception. so my question is weather there is a way to catch if IT360Counts["router"] exists sor not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when `IT360Counts["router"]` is not null but an empty list. In that case `IT360Counts["router"].SingleOrDefault()` will return null, so when accessing its `ItemCount` property you will get a null exception.

This happens because the indexer in the `Lookup` returns an empty list when the key is not found. See [remarks section in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try checking if the lookup contains the key, `IT360Counts.Contains("router")`. This way you can do:

```
IT360RouterNo =  IT360Counts.Contains("router") ? IT360Counts["router"].SingleOrDefault().ItemCount : 0,
```

As a side note, have you also considered using `ToDictionary` instead of `ToLookup`? The dictionary key would be your Action and the value the ItemCount, so when retrieving the values you just get the value in the dictionary for a key like `"router"`. If you are you always doing `.SingleOrDefault().ItemCount` and **never** expect more than one item with the same Action, you may be better using a dictionary.

For the sake of completion this idea would be:

```
var IT360Counts = entities.Resources.Where(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ASSETTAG) &&(a.SystemInfo.ISSERVER == true))
                          .GroupBy(a => a.SystemInfo.MODEL.ToLower())
                          .Select(g => new
                          {
                              Action = g.Key.ToLower(),
                              ItemCount = g.Count()
                          }).ToDictionary(a => a.Action, a => a.ItemCount);

IT360RouterNo =  IT360Counts.ContainsKey("router") ? IT360Counts["router"] : 0,
```

Hope it helps!